# MousePosition in AttachedCell?

Tags: bugs, front-end, dynamic, cells

I can't figure out why the following stops working when `"WindowAbsolute"` is replaced with `"Graphics"`?

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
  FrontEnd`AttachCell[EvaluationCell[], 
   Cell[BoxData[
     DynamicBox[
      ToBoxes[MousePosition["WindowAbsolute"]]]], 
    "Output", 
    Background -> LightBlue], {Offset[{0, -15}, 15], {Left, 
     Bottom}}, {Left, Top}, "ClosingActions" -> {"OutsideMouseClick"}]];
```

[image]

Comment: interestingly, the attached cell contents update properly to show positions in graphics objects in _other_ open notebooks (not those in the evaluation notebook).

Comment: Perhaps this isn't the correct way to instantiate an attached cell?

Comment: M.R.  curious about the use case(s) you have in mind.

Comment: Just spelunking into attached cells

Comment: My guess is this is simply a bug. Something about how these messages get passed up and down the chain must skip `AttachedCell` somewhere. Also look at what you get for ``"CellContentsAbsolute"``. It's bonkers and clearly incorrect.

Comment: Perhaps there’s some other workaround way to get the graphics mouse position?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I contacted WRI and it **is a bug**. Sadly it won't be fixed for v12 because it requires rewriting few fundamentals parts of code for `AttachedCells`.

As **a workaround** you can emit graphics position from graphics you care about. So wrap an `EventHandler` around your plots that will `myVariable = MousePosition["Graphics"]` on `MouseMoved` event.

You can use regular `myVariable` but you need to take care about scoping/collisions which I think is case dependent.

Let's create **an example** which assumes that everyiong is revolving around a single UI as opposed to a whole notebook. We can utilize Dynamic Wormholes for that:

```
DynamicModule[{position} 
, EventHandler[
    ListPlot @ Prime @ Range @ 25
  , { "MouseMoved" :> (position = CurrentValue[{"MousePosition", "Graphics"}])
    , "MouseExited" :> (position = None)
    }
  ] 
, Initialization :> (
   position = None

 ; MathLink`CallFrontEnd @ FrontEnd`AttachCell[
     EvaluationCell[]
   , Cell[ 
       BoxData @ ToBoxes @ Framed @ DynamicModule[
         {}, Dynamic @ position, InheritScope -> True
       ]
     , "Output"
     ]
   , {Offset[{0, -15}, 15], {Left, Bottom}}
   , {Left, Top}
   , "ClosingActions" -> {"OutsideMouseClick"}
   ]
  )
]
```

[image]

For general, notebook wide solution, you could save it in `CurrentValue[nb, {TaggingRules, "GraphicsPosition"}]` but somehow refreshing of `Dynamic @ CurrentValue[nb, {TaggingRules, "GraphicsPosition"}]` reacts very slowly to such changes (see answer edit history for a code example).

Comment: Ah right, duh, so this is definitely faster, obviously the to-from the kernel isn't the bottleneck here...

Comment: @M.R. please see the edit, let me know if there is anything missing.